# Durandal view composition order

Tags: durandal

Durandal 2.0 - view composition order

I have view, that has a number of child views that I am using just to break up the HTML into separate files.

```
index.html(index.js)
     - menu.html
     - header.html
     - footer.html
```

The menu view is populated by the index view after it's loaded.

Inside the index.html I compose the menu view like this (there is no module menu.js, just html composition here):

```
<!--ko compose: {  view: 'menu'}--><!--/ko-->
```

The problem is the order of the view composition.

I have an attached event wired up in index.js that then calls a function to populate the menu div that's sat in menu.html.

But, the attached view event is called *before* the menu.html view has been composed.

The events looks something like this from the console:

```
Binding views/footer 
Binding views/index 
binding complete: <section data-view=​"views/​index" style=​"display:​ none;​">​…​</section>​
[Index]  Main View Attached 
Binding views/header 
Binding views/menu 
Binding views/menudropdown
```

So, the main view is attached before the children.

Is there a way to change the composition order, or wait for all the child views to be composed/loaded before the main view is attached/complete?

Thanks

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem that you wish to solve?  Is the order of composition actually creating a problem?  It seems logical that your parent view should load first, and then the children.

Comment: It seems you could defer firing activation complete to make the attached event wait to fire but it just changes the timing of the events firing, not the order.

Comment: Eric - yes, I need the DOM loaded in the child view so I can initialise the menu (kendo treeview).

Comment: one way I found to do it was to create a binding handler, and inside the binding handler you get the viewModel in the init parameters and then simply call a function to initialise the menu.  I know it's not the best setup; I'll probably try to refactor it, just trying to get it working for now.

Comment: @jiggle O.K., then.  Could you possibly post each of your view files and viewmodel files, the pertinent bits?  Posting a fiddle of what is working right now (even if not correctly) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "*no*" - you can't change the composition order.

The longer answer: perhaps I've misunderstood, but it sounds a little bit suspicious that you're populating the menu `div` from your view model. Could you use a custom binding to do this instead? If you *can* do it in a binding, then you could have a look at using a [**Delayed Binding Handler**](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html). From the documentation:

> Sometimes your binding handler needs to work with an element only
>   after it is attached to the DOM and when the entire composition of the
>   view is complete. An example of this is any code that needs to measure
>   the size of an HTML element. Durandal provides a way to register a
>   knockout binding handler so that it does not execute until the
>   composition is complete. To do this, use
>   `composition.addBindingHandler`.

Alternatively, if you're happy with whatever code is running in your viewModel, you probably want to use the `compositionComplete` event rather than the `attached` event. From memory, the `attached` events run from parent to child (which is why the event is being called on index before the menu has been composed). In contrast, [`compositionComplete` bubbles from child to parent](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks):

> Finally, when the entire composition process is complete, including
>   any parent and child compositions, the composition engine will call
>   the `compositionComplete(view, parent)` callback, bubbling from child to
>   parent.

You can attach a `compositionComplete` handler on your viewModel in the same fashion as an activate method:

```
// Secured Shell
define([], function () {
    var viewModel = {
        activate: function () {
            // do stuff
        },

        compositionComplete: function (parent, child, settings) {
            // do more stuff
            debugger;
        }
    };

    return viewModel;
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks gerrod, the compositionComplete was the key and that fires when everything has been composed, so my menu div is available and I can call the intialisation for it.  I know it's not ideal, but for now I just wanted to separate the HTML, and this works.  Later I will refactor to a better design.  Thanks again.